# Update RecyclerView from Dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

how to update recyclerview from a dialog which is in another class?

My dialog is as a separate class which is called from mainActivity. When I do changes in database, I would like to update recyclerview, which is on mainActivity.

Dialog:

```
public class Dialog {

DatabaseExecutor databaseExecutor = new DatabaseExecutor();
private final Activity activity;
private final List<Passenger> passengers;
private final int position;

public Dialog (final Activity activity, final List<Passenger> passengers, final int position){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.position = position;
}

public void showDialog (){
    final BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(activity);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    final AppCompatImageView dial, message, info, paid, edit, delete;
    final AppCompatTextView name;

    name = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name);
    paid = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_paid);

    name.setText(passengers.get(position).getName());
    if(passengers.get(position).isPaid())
        paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_paid_72);
    else
        paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_unpaid_72);

    paid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Passenger passenger = passengers.get(position);
            if (!passengers.get(position).isPaid()){
                passenger.setPaid(true);
                passenger.setTumblr(R.drawable.money_paid);
                passenger.setUser(R.drawable.user_icon);
                paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_paid_72);
            }
            else {
                passenger.setPaid(false);
                passenger.setTumblr(R.drawable.money_unpaid);
                passenger.setUser(R.drawable.user_icon_unpaid);
                paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_unpaid_72);
            }
            databaseExecutor.updatePassenger(activity, passenger);
        }
    });
dialog.show();
}
}
```

P.s. when this dialog was in mainActivity, I just called populateData method and it worked. But how to refresh it from this Dialog class?

Comment: Why is the recyclerView not getting information from the database. When the dialog updates the database, shouldn't that be visible when you open the recycler view after that with the information from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct solution would be to call method on activity you passed to the dialog. There refresh data of recyclerview and notifyDataSetChanged() or appropriate.

A more general and imo better, architecture-related solution is to use Room or similar db, where you can observe data for changes. Let's say data in the db is changed anywhere. All the places where this data is observed (like with LiveData), data is refreshed. If you also use Paging library, data is refreshed and animated in recyclerview too.

Comment: Yes, I am using Room database, but guess wasn't mature enough to implement Live Data :D Gonna dive deeper into it now. Ty!

Comment: Any questions, just ask ;) With room db it's easy to get livedata. Also check the paging library, it does all the work for the recyclerview.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `callback` with dialog in `MainActivity`,

```
public interface DialogCallback {
    public void onDialogCallback();
}
```

Your `Dialog` constructor should be,

```
DialogCallback callback;

public Dialog (final Activity activity, final List<Passenger> passengers, final int position, DialogCallback callback){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.position = position;
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

In your Dialog button click use below code,

```
paid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Passenger passenger = passengers.get(position);
        if (!passengers.get(position).isPaid()){
            passenger.setPaid(true);
            passenger.setTumblr(R.drawable.money_paid);
            passenger.setUser(R.drawable.user_icon);
            paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_paid_72);
        }
        else {
            passenger.setPaid(false);
            passenger.setTumblr(R.drawable.money_unpaid);
            passenger.setUser(R.drawable.user_icon_unpaid);
            paid.setImageResource(R.drawable.money_unpaid_72);
        }
        databaseExecutor.updatePassenger(activity, passenger);
        callback.onDialogCallback(); // Add this line
    }
});
```

In your `MainActivity` use below code,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, passengers, position, new DialogCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDialogCallback() {
        // Update recycler view code here
    }
});
dialog.showDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Dialog :

Have an interface

`public interface onDialogFinishCallback
    {
        void refreshRecyclerView();
    }`

Now implement the above in your activity.

before dismiss the dialog or after the db change operation call
`callback.refreshRecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Dialog shouldn't refresh RecyclverView directly. Instead you should pass listener from activity. Activity can refresh recycler if needed with `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Usually dialog should be 'dumb' ui and you shouldn't give it too much control, especially not over elements that are not shown inside dialog. Such approach will make your dialogs more reusable and easy to maintain.

Comment: I agree, it is not recommended to pass the activity around everywhere.

Comment: I pass activity to dialog only for two reasons: first, to show it on mainActivity; second, to communicate with db

Answer (score 0):

Write an interface in your dialog

`public interface onClickInterface{
    public void updateRecyclerView(int position);
}`

declare new variable for this interface in your dialog class

```
private onClickInterface mOnClickInterface;
```

then call method updateRecyclerView() from dialog class where you want to update recyclerview

```
mOnClickInterface.updateRecyclerView(position);
```

then implement your MainActivity for this interface and override this method

```
@override    
public void updateRecyclerView(int position){
     //alter your list which you are passing to your adapter
     Passenger passenger = passengers.get(position);
     passenger.setPaid(true);
     rAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```